# What is the purpose of Kosovo's Application Request to Join EU if several EU members do not recognize its independence?

Tags: european-union, kosovo

At the end of 2022 Kosovo's leaders (..) [signed a formal application](https://www.voanews.com/a/kosovo-leaders-sign-application-request-to-join-eu/6877175.html) seeking the status of candidate for membership in the European Union.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accession_of_Kosovo_to_the_European_Union), five EU members do not recognize Kosovo's independence, so it sounds like they are unlikely to agree with it joining the EU.

Considering this, what is the purpose of asking to be a candidate for membership in the European Union? What are the advantages of obtaining this status, if joining the EU seems very unlikely in the next few years?